# OnClick Button Sound link with an ImageView

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn to program a simple app in (Android Studio), in this app I have 10 images which I programmed them with ImageSwitcher to go next or previous, Now I want to have a button which plays my 10 audios according to each image. Example when the Image I1 is shown and user presses PLAY button then Audio A1 plays, and the same for the rest I2=A2, I3=A3 and ...
Any help would be great and is appreciated.
with best regards

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add your audio files in the raw folder. Then create an array with reference of image array put names of audio accordingly

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Context context = this;
MediaPlayer mp;
int audioList[] = [R.raw.audio1, R.raw.audio2........]

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, audioList[currentIndex]);
            try {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, audioList[currentIndex]);
                } mp.start();
            } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Hope this works for you.
Happy Coding

Comment: Glad to know. If this was helpful for you then please up vote it.

Comment: Dear Abhishek, again really thank you for your help, and I already voted.